# Not able to create payment plan agreement

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Unable to create PayPal payment agreement. getting error response.

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"2c640b4ae1908"}
```

Sending JSON Request:

```
{"name":"Base Agreement","description":"Basic Agreement","start_date":"2019-04-09T00:00:00Z","plan":{"id":"P-0XM25908D436124367U2FLSI"},"payer":{"payment_method":"credit_card","funding_instruments":[{"payment_card":{"type":"amex","number":"372336613695525","expire_month":"9","expire_year":"2028","cvv2":"5681","first_name":"Buyer","last_name":" ","billing_country":"US","billing_address":"8484848484"}}]},"shipping_address":{"line1":"38 Street, aa","city":"New York","state":"New York","postal_code":"10011","country_code":"US"}}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not including all of the required data. Look at the required lines for [the plan object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#definition-plan)

Comment: the link you are sending is for create plan. but my plan is successfully created and got plan id. after getting plan id trying to create payment agreement.

Comment: It's hard to tell if it is dummy data or not, but regardless: please obfuscate credit card data (at least the PAN) before pasting it here

Answer (score 0):

You have payment_method set to credit_card.  This is not available for billing agreements according to the documentation for the [payments.billing-agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/#definition-payer).

[image]

If you want to setup agreements with direct credit cards I think you're going to need to use [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com) at this point.  They killed REST credit cards awhile ago.